# Recovering an A-infinity structure on an Ext-algebra from a quiver presentation

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra, a-infinity-algebras

Let $A=KQ/I$ be a basic finite dimensional algebra given by a quiver with relations. Let $S$ denote the direct sum of the corresponding simple modules. 
According to [Keller: A-infinity algebras in representation theory; Proposition 2], it is possible to derive the/an A-infinity structure on $\operatorname{Ext}^*(S,S)$  from the presentation $KQ/I$ as follows:

Note that $D(J/J^2)\cong \operatorname{Ext}^1(S,S)$ and $D(I/(JI+IJ))\cong \operatorname{Ext}^2(S,S)$. Choose a splitting $s\colon I/(IJ+JI)\to I$ of the canonical surjection. Then (using the identifications) the restriction of the A-infinity structure to $\operatorname{Ext}^1(S,S)^{\otimes n}\to \operatorname{Ext}^2(S,S)$ can be  given by the dual of the map $\iota s$, where $\iota\colon I\to KQ$ is the canonical inclusion and $Q$ is identified with a basis for $J/J^2$.

Unfortunately, Keller's survey paper doesn't contain a proof of that statement. In [Lu, Palmieri, Wu, Zhang: A-infinity structures on Ext-algebras], a variant of the proposition for connected graded algebras is proven. Are there other similar statements to that proposition in the literature? Is a proof published somewhere?

Comment: A slightly cleaner presented (I think) version of the proof you mention is in the paper of He and Lu "Higher Koszul algebras and A-infinity algebras", Theorem 5.2. Is there some part of the proof that you believe does not adapt for quivers with relations (essentially) without changes?

Comment: @VladimirDotsenko Thank you, this is indeed cleaner. I saw the reference in LPWZ, but hadn't looked at it properly yet. I want to prove a certain generalisation of this theorem, so different proofs might be more or less suitable for generalisation. I had sketch-proved the adaption of LPWZ for quivers with relations before.